# Normalizer of the normalizer of the sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, how do I prove that normalizer of the normalizer $P$ is same as the normalizer of $P$ ?

Comment: This was a question on the 1995 Columbia Algebra qual, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is an exercise from Fraleigh's *A First Course In Abstract Algebra* (7e), if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is the first exercise on page $82$ of N. Jacobson's Basic Algebra I (e2), if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is exercise 5.8 in Isaacs $\textit{Algebra A Graduate Course}$, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is exercise 2.12.17 from Herstein's Topics in Algebra, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is Theorem 5.11 in Hungerford's $\textit{Algebra}$, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is exercise 4.5.32 in Dummit &Foote's Abstract Algebra, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is exercise 14 from chapter 9 in Felipe Zaldívar's $\textit{Introducción a la Teoría de Grupos}$, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is exercise 23 (c) at the end of chapter 1 of Serge Lang's *Algebra*, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This is [Question 67008](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/normalizer-of-the-normalizer-of-the-sylow-p-subgroup) on [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), if anyone was wondering.

Comment: This post has migrated to [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1567682496877142/permalink/3361978737447500/), if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We have the following: $P\leq N(P)\leq N(N(P))$. We see that $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-group of $N(P)$ and of $N(N(P))$. If $x\in N(N(P))$, then $xPx^{-1}\leq xN(P)x^{-1}=N(P)$, and since all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, we have that there exists $y\in N(P)$ such that $xPx^{-1}=yPy^{-1}$. But since $y\in N(P)$, we have that $yPy^{-1}=P$, and so $xPx^{-1}=P$. This shows that $x\in N(P)$, and they must be the same.

Comment: Can I ask why  y∈N(P) ?

Comment: $P$, $xPx^{-1}$ are Sylow subgroups of $N(P)$. By Sylow's theorem, they are conjugate *in $N(P)$* : there is $y\in N(P)$ such that $yPy^{-1} = xPx^{-1}$

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Answer (score 18):

Let $M= N_G(P)$. Clearly, $M\subseteq N_G(M)$.

Now, notice that $P$ is normal in $M$, so it is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$. Therefore, if $x\in N_G(M)$, then since $xPx^{-1}$ is *a* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $xMx^{-1}=M$, then $xPx^{-1} = P$, because $P$ is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$. That means that $x\in N_G(P) = M$. Therefore, $N_G(M)\subseteq N_G(P)$.

Comment: The notation is strange - shouldn't it be $N_G(P)$?

Comment: @qwr Don’t know how that happened 7 years ago...

Comment: I'm sorry. I wanted to upvote but by mistake I downvoted your answer. Now I can't change it.

Answer (score 10):

Hints ($N(H)$ denotes the normalizer of a subgroup $H\le G$ in $G$):

1) Show that $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of$N(P)$. Remember that they are all conjugate in $N(P)$.

2) If $P$ and $P'$ are different Sylow $p$-subgroups, show that $N(P)$ and $N(P')$ are A) conjugate in $G$, B) different.

3) Show that $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N(N(P))$.

4) Show that $P\unlhd N(N(P))$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: P is a normal Sylow p-subgroup of $N_G(P)$...

Answer (score 6):

Another proof

We have that $P\in\text{Syl}_p(\mathbf{N}_G(P))$ and $\mathbf{N}_G(P)\trianglelefteq \mathbf{N}_G(\mathbf{N}_G(P))$. By Frattini's Argument:
$$\mathbf{N}_{\mathbf{N}_G(\mathbf{N}_G(P\,))}(P)\cdot\mathbf{N}_G(P)=\mathbf{N}_G(P)=\mathbf{N}_G(\mathbf{N}_G(P)),$$ because $\mathbf{N}_{\mathbf{N}_G(\mathbf{N}_G(P\,))}(P)\subseteq \mathbf{N}_G(P)$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $N=N_G(P)$. Let $x\in N_G(N)$, so that $xNx^{-1}=N$. Then $xPx^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N\leq G$. Since $P$ is normal in $N$, $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. Therefore $xPx^{-1}=P$. This implies $x\in N$. We have proved $N_G(N_G(P))\subseteq N_G(P)$.

Let $y\in N_G(P)$ Then certainly $yN_G(P)y^{-1}=N_G(P)$, so that $y\in N_G(N_G(P))$. Thus $N_G(P)\subseteq N_G(N_G(P))$.

Answer (score 5):

There are many answers already but I'll give anoter one (I didn't see it somewhere above).

It is based on the following proposition:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$. If $N_G(P)\leq H\leq G$ then $H=N_G(H)$.

*Proof*: Let $g\in N_G(H)$. Then $P\leq H\Rightarrow gPg^{-1}\subseteq gHg^{-1}=H$. So $P,gPg^{-1}$ are Sylow $p-$subgroups of $H$. Hence they are conjugate, i.e. there exists $h\in H$ s.t. $P=hgPg^{-1}h^{-1}\Rightarrow hg\in N_G(P)\leq H\Rightarrow g\in H\Rightarrow N_G(H)\subseteq H\checkmark$.

Now, apply the proposition for $H=N_G(P)$.