# Are the normalizers of Sylow p-subgroups isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A,B \in \text{Syl}_p G$, for some prime $p$. Is it always true that the normalizers $N_G(A)\cong N_G(B)$?
I just need a **hint** to get started, because I don't know where to begin...

Comment: If $A^g=B$, then $N_G(A)^g=N_G(B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $gAg^{-1}=B$ and $h$ normalizes $B$, then $hgAg^{-1}h^{-1}=B$, hence $$g^{-1}hgAg^{-1}h^{-1}g=A$$
What does this tell you?

Comment: $N_G(B)=N_G(gAg^{-1})= \{k\in G : k^{-1}gAg^{-1}k=gAg^{-1}\} = \{k\in G : g^{-1}k^{-1}gAg^{-1}kg=A\}$. By substituting $l=g^{-1}kg$, the last set is $\{glg^{-1}: l\in G \land l^{-1}Al=A\} = gN_G(A)g^{-1}$. Is it correct? I thought it was more difficult :)

Comment: @Human yep. Easier than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Additional fun fact: now that you know that $N_G(P)^g=N_G(P^g)$, you can ask yourself the question: how many *different* conjugates $N_G(P)^g$ of the Sylow $p$-group $P$ are there anyway? Well, in general, basic group theory tells you that a subgroup $H$ has $|G:N_G(H)|$ many different conjugates. So, in our case this is $|G:N_G(N_G(P))|$. However, it is a well-known fact that for a Sylow $p$-subgroup $N_G(N_G(P))=N_G(P)$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/normalizer-of-the-normalizer-of-the-sylow-p-subgroup). So the answer to the question is $|G:N_G(P)|$, which is exactly the number of different Sylow $p$-subgroups!