# Why $N_G(N_G(H)) = N_G(H)$ for some subgroup H < G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to show that $N_G(N_G(H)) = N_G(H)$ for some subgroup H < G. I also understand that the normalizer is described as the largest group which H is normal to, but I don't know how to use that information in a proof.

**My attempt**

I have shown that $N_G(H) \subseteq N_G(N_G(H))$ since $N_G(H)\lhd N_G(N_G(H)).$

I now want to show that $N_G(N_G(H)) \subseteq N_G(H)$, but I'm getting stuck. Here's what I have so far:

We need to show that if $$x \in N_G(N_G(H)) \Rightarrow x \in N_G(H).$$

i.e. $$xN_G(H)x^{-1} = N_G(H) \Rightarrow xhx^{-1} \in H$$

To show this, I considered taking an element $y \in N_G(H)$, but after that I'm lost. Can anyone provide some insight for how I should continue?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Can you provide a counterexample? How do you know it's not true?

Comment: If you additionally assume that $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then this is true. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/normalizer-of-the-normalizer-of-the-sylow-p-subgroup

Comment: That's bizarre. The problem statement that I was assigned was, "Prove that for any subgroup H, $N_G(N_G(H)) = N_G(H)$."

Comment: In the interest of providing you with a counter-example, I think if we take $G = D_{3} = \{I, F_{1}, F_{2}, F_{3}, R^{120^{\circ}}, R^{240^{\circ}} \}$, and $H = \{I,F_{1} \}$, I believe we have $N_{G}(H) = \{I,F_{1}, R^{120^{\circ}}, R^{240^{\circ}} \}$, and $N_{G}(N_{G}(H)) = G$, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I'm slightly unfamiliar with the notation here. Would $F_2$ be the same as $R^{120^o}F_1?$

Comment: @JonathanHebert Your example does not work. A group of order $6$ cannot have a subgroup of order $4$. A similar example with $D_4$ works.

Comment: Woops, sorry! That's what I get for going through that too quickly.

Comment: I don't believe that the example with $D_4$ works either. The normalizer of the subgroup $\{I, F_1\}$ is the subgroup itself, so the normalizer of the normalizer will be the same as the normalizer.

Comment: That's not true, the normalizer in $D_4$ of $\{1,F_1\}$ has order $4$ and includes the rotation through $180^\circ$.

Comment: Oh yes! I believe that is correct. Working this out, with $H = \{1, F\}$ we can conclude that $N_G(H) = \{1, F, R^{180^o}, R^{180^o}F\}$ and $N_G(N_G(H)) = D_8$. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I figured that I would go ahead and place an answer to my question here.

The proposition stated in the question is false, unless (as Kenny Wong stated) H is a Sylow p-subgroup. The link to a proof of that is located here: [Normalizer of the normalizer of the sylow $p$-subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/normalizer-of-the-normalizer-of-the-sylow-p-subgroup).

To show that the the statement is false, examine the counterexample $D_8$, i.e. the set of symmetries on a square. (Sometimes, this is denoted as $D_4$).

$$G := D_8 = \{e,\ r,\ r^2,\ r^3,\ f,\ fr,\ fr^2,\ fr^3\}$$ where $r$ is a 90 degree rotation, and f is a flip. Let $H$ be $\{e,\ f\}$. Obviously, $H < G$.

$$N_G(H) = \{e,\ f,\ r^2,\ fr^2\}$$
$$\text{Then, }N_G(N_G(H)) = D_8.$$
$$\text{So, }N_G(H) \neq N_G(N_G(H)).$$